# Meaning of "lead conversions"

Tags: meaning, nouns

In the context of enterprises developing software what is the meaning of the phrase "lead conversions"?

Comment: Can you give a full sentence (or even paragraph) for context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both words have particular meanings in the context of sales/corporate jargon.

*Leads* are **sales leads:** potential customers. (This doesn't appear in [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lead?q=lead) and isn't really represented in the OED entry which hasn't been updated since 1902.)

> **lead**
>   **32.**
>   a suggestion or piece of information that helps to direct or guide; tip; clue:
>      *I got a lead on a new job.
>
>      The phone list provided some great sales leads.*
>
> [[dictionary.com]](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lead)

*Conversions* are those potential customers who actually become customers.

> **conversion**
>   **4** (also **conversion rate**) (in the context of online marketing) the proportion of people viewing an advertisement and going on to buy the product, click on a link, etc.:
>      *you’ll see better conversion rates for your local advertising if you include your physical address on your website
>
>      keeping things simple will improve conversion*
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/conversion?q=conversion)

Comment: I'd be interested to know why this answer "is not useful" and how to make it more useful.